# complex numbers from real closed fields

Tags: complex-numbers, first-order-logic

I am very interested in first order axiomatizations of the complex numbers, but I have never actually seen one laid out.  Algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero are a start, but they don't have any axioms handling the real and imaginary parts, or any kind of metric/partial order.  A field extension of real closed fields would probably do the job.  Most articles on real closed fields mention that this is possible, but I haven't seen any that actually lay it out axiomatically.  Could anyone point me to resources on the topic?

Comment: That's a nice question. I would guess that is not possible without extending the signature of the language  (e.g., to include conjugation, or a constant for $i$ and a predicate for the reals).

Comment: I should have said (apologetically) in my earlier comment that I don't know of any relevant references with details. Thinking some more, I see that it is essential that you extend the signature (it is impossible to characterise $\mathbb{R}$ as a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ using just the language of a field). So you need to do something like: add a constant for $i$ and a predicate $R(z)$ for the reals; add axioms saying that the reals are a real closed subfield, that $i^2 = -1$ and that any element has the form $x + iy$ for $x, y$ satisfying $R(x)$ and $R(y)$.